# loop for to insert row in a mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, if-statement, sql-insert

I have a for loop with php but is not working properly. Inside the for loop I have an "if" and an "else", but the loop stops iterate in the first "else" and should continue. Here is the code:

```
//counting the rows in database and the rows I want to insert

$total = count($rowToInsert); //for example 10 values
$totalDB = count($rowDB); // for example 5 values

// the for loop starts

for ($i=0; $i < $total; $i++){ //it should iterate until 10 values

  if(isset($rowDB[$i])){ //change the first 5 values

   $update = "UPDATE table SET name = '$name[$i]' WHERE ID = $rowToInsert[$i]";
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $update);

  } else { //it should iterate from sixth until tenth value

   $insert = "INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES ('$name[$i]')";
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $insert);

  // here is the next code

  $newTable = 'table'.$rowToInsert[$i];

  $newDB = "CREATE DATABASE $newTable CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
  $resultDB = mysqli_query($con, $newDB);

  // select the DB

  mysqli_select_db($con, $newTable) or die ("not found");

  } //end of else

} //end of for
```

The thing is if the database contain 5 rows and I want to insert, for example, 10 rows, the code works updating the first 5 with the new value, then it jumps to the "else" and starts to iterate in the sixth value and it works, but the next values doesn't.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Hector

Comment: Put the $i on your loop for ($i=0; $i < $total; $i++){

you are missing to put $i

Comment: oh sorry, that was just a transcribe issue, in the code is right

Comment: Trying to be used mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES ('$name[$i]')"); .

Comment: I have some values coming from an ajax (arrays) and if the ID exist in the table it update the value, if not create a new row in the table. I think is not an error of syntax because it iterate the first else inserting the row number 6, but it stops there and i need that the for loop continue until 10. So I think it could be a logic problem

Comment: I couldn't found any logic problem on your post . Make sure you have array with 10 key on $name[$i]. I think it's happend for not getting data on $name[$i]

Comment: For testing purpose put some static value instead of $name[$i] and $rowToInsert[$i]. If static value are works then you can easily find out the problem :)

Comment: Yeah i did it. Actually the data is a table in html, when you press "save" it send an ajax to php and do the code that i posted. I made a "print_r" in each array and put an alert in ajax and show me the data so the value $name[$i] is not empty. The strange part is inside the "else" after the insert there is another code to create new tables and it works. So the problem is specifically with this insert. I really don't know what is it. Im gonna try to do what you say, instead of use a variable, i will put the insert inside the brackets.

Comment: Let me know after try this

Comment: you never check for mysql errors

Comment: remove the parenthesis from the $rowToInsert[$i] since ID is supposed to be an int I am guessing?

Comment: I put some mysql errors and i found the error, but i don't know how to solve it. after the result, i create a new database with the name of "table" plus the ID. Then I select the database created and add some tables inside it. When the iteration tries to get the next table says that can't find the table. I edited the post to add the code.

Comment: You should use INSERT ON DUPLICATE, REPLACE and CREATE IF NOT EXIST (no need for if else) and for safety use binds https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Patrick, this looks interesting...i will check it and let you know..thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. In the else loop, when the iteration tries to select the database, for some reason it takes part of the name of the last iteration, so it couldn't find the database. The solution (maybe is not so clean) is connect and close the database connection in every iteration. The code stays like this:

```
//counting the rows in database and the rows I want to insert

$total = count($rowToInsert); //for example 10 values
$totalDB = count($rowDB); // for example 5 values

// the for loop starts

for ($i=0; $i < $total; $i++){ //it should iterate until 10 values

  if(isset($rowDB[$i])){ //change the first 5 values

   $update = "UPDATE table SET name = '$name[$i]' WHERE ID = $rowToInsert[$i]";
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $update);

  } else { //it should iterate from sixth until tenth value

   // reconnect to db

   $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("unable to connect");
   $db = "database";

   $insert = "INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES ('$name[$i]')";
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $insert);

  // here is the next code

  $newTable = 'table'.$rowToInsert[$i];

  $newDB = "CREATE DATABASE $newTable CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
  $resultDB = mysqli_query($con, $newDB);

  // select the DB

  mysqli_select_db($con, $newTable) or die ("not found");

  //close the connection to db;

  $con->close();

  } //end of else

} //end of for
```

Thanks you all for inspiring the answer!

Hector